# How to conditionally add a new column with a new date time based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
datadf = {'Date':  ['2010-03-15', '2014-03-21','2019-02-26','2017-02-26'],
        'Follow': ['3 years', '5 years','3 years','1 year']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (datadf)
```

I want to create a new column where if Follow= 3 years then 3 years are added to the date in the Date column, in a new column. The same should apply for if 5 years, then add 5 years and so on.

I can do this for a single condition as below:

```
df["DateUpdate"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=53) 
                            if '3 years' in x['Follow'] else x['Date'],
                            axis=1)
```

but how to extend for all the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Follow` is in format `n years` or `n year`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':  ['2010-03-15', '2014-03-21','2019-02-26','2017-02-26'],
        'Follow': ['3 years', '5 years','3 years','1 year']
        })

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['DateUpdate'] = df.apply(lambda r: 
                            r['Date']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(
                                years=float(r["Follow"].split()[0])), axis=1)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
Date    Follow  DateUpdate
0   2010-03-15  3 years 2013-03-15
1   2014-03-21  5 years 2019-03-21
2   2019-02-26  3 years 2022-02-26
3   2017-02-26  1 year  2018-02-26
```

#### Update 1:

Generalizing it to work ok all the `offsets` supported by `DateOffset` but assuming the format of `Follow` to be `n offsetstring` or `Not available`.

```
def do_offset(row):
    date, follow = row['Date'], row['Follow']
    allowed_offsets = [ "years", "months", "weeks", "days", 
                       "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "microseconds"]
    if follow != "Not available":
        n, offset = follow.lower().split()
        # For year, month, ...        
        offset = offset+"s" if offset[-1] != "s"  else offset 
        if offset in allowed_offsets:
            date = date+pd.offsets.DateOffset(**{offset:float(n)})
    return date


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':  ['2010-03-15']*10,
        'Follow': ['1 year', '3 years', '3 months', '3 weeks', 
                   '3 days', '3 hours', '3 minutes', '3 seconds', 
                   '3 microseconds', 'Not available']
        })

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['DateUpdate'] = df.apply(do_offset, axis=1)

print (df)
```

Output:

```
        Date          Follow                 DateUpdate
0 2010-03-15          1 year 2011-03-15 00:00:00.000000
1 2010-03-15         3 years 2013-03-15 00:00:00.000000
2 2010-03-15        3 months 2010-06-15 00:00:00.000000
3 2010-03-15         3 weeks 2010-04-05 00:00:00.000000
4 2010-03-15          3 days 2010-03-18 00:00:00.000000
5 2010-03-15         3 hours 2010-03-15 03:00:00.000000
6 2010-03-15       3 minutes 2010-03-15 00:03:00.000000
7 2010-03-15       3 seconds 2010-03-15 00:00:03.000000
8 2010-03-15  3 microseconds 2010-03-15 00:00:00.000003
9 2010-03-15   Not available 2010-03-15 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: Thanks @mujjiga that's a smart answer. Can you tell me whether I can use a nested form eg what if one of the entry strings in df['Follow'] was '6 months' or 'Not available' so that each rule had to be written out?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the **Date** column to datetime. Then extract no of years to add from **Follow** column using `regex` and finally add those years to **Date** column using `pd.DateOffset(years)`

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df["New_Date"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Date + pd.DateOffset(years= int(re.findall(r"(\d) year", x.Follow)[0])) , axis =1)
print(df)


           Date     Follow   New_Date
    0   2010-03-15  3 years 2013-03-15
    1   2014-03-21  5 years 2019-03-21
    2   2019-02-26  3 years 2022-02-26
    3   2017-02-26  1 year  2018-02-26
```